# Synonyms for 'right in the'

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, word-usage, synonyms

What are some synonyms for right in the/at the?

e.g.

> Get milk **right at** your doorstep.
>
> Watch movies **right in** your tablet.

Or, alternatively, what are some synonyms for "itself"?

e.g.

> Get milk at your doorstep **itself**.
>
> Watch moves in your tablet **itself**.

Comment: Also _milk at your very doorstep_, which is an odd construction because _very_ can modify a noun. They all mean to emphasize the closeness and convenience of what's being discussed. It's like "pizza in your own home" (like you own several, only one of which is your "own"). Idioms, the lot.

Comment: @JohnLawler so how can we best put it.... like i am trying to show how convenient it would be for using this.... eg ' VLC player - watch movies right in ur tablet'...is there a better way to put forth it, because it could also be read as 'watch movies right'....'in ur tablet'

Comment: I find your "right in your iPad" construction very odd. More so than milk "right at (on?) your doorstep", perhaps because having milk delivered is not the prime function of a doorstep, whereas the iPad is largely about movies anyway. Would you say that the maitre d' showed you right to your table? That the plane flew right to the airport? (What else would it do, god forbid?)

Comment: It's tricky with E-terminology because **everything** is a metaphor; there were no English words for anything electronic before 1940, so we've plundered every metaphoric connection available, and you can't tell, for instance, whether _in_ (for containers) or _on_ (for surfaces) is appropriate for whatever image the reader is using. Something can be _on_ the radio, TV, a list, a poster, a schedule, a hard disk, for instance, or _in_ a file, a book, a paper, an article, a podcast, a computer.

Comment: Right 'on' your tablet is possibly a slightly better construction than 'in'.

Comment: I’m wondering why you are even trying to avoid the ambiguity that you mentioned in your comment above: ('watch movies right'....'in ur tablet').  Although I’d definitely change the “in” to “on,” (especially for the tablet, but also for the milk), both interpretations are positive for the product/service and the ambiguity is, imo, somewhat clever and at worst is not negative: “Watch movies [the] right [way] ON your tablet”/” Get milk [the] right [way] ON your doorstep.

Answer (score 3):

Milk *[delivered](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deliver?q=delivered)*...*[on your doorstep](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+doorstep)*:

> also *at your doorstep*
>   very near to you
>
> *Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright © Cambridge
>   University Press 2003.*

---

Movies *[delivered on your IPad](https://www.google.com/search?q=mumbai&oq=mumbai&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2366j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=%22delivered%20on%20your%20IPad%22)* is slightly more popular than movies *[delivered to your IPad](https://www.google.com/search?q=mumbai&oq=mumbai&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2366j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=%22delivered%20to%20your%20IPad%22)*. It seems an IPad is sometimes viewed like a television or radio with the preposition *on*, and sometimes like a location with the preposition *to*. But Movies *[delivered in your IPad](https://www.google.com/search?q=mumbai&oq=mumbai&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2366j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=%22delivered+in+your+IPad%22)* is not popular at all.

Answer (score 0):

The idium is referring to things happening more quickly or directly - no middle man or travelling required so it is simple and easy.

While i can see this is the meaning you are trying to use, for your example "Watch movies right in your tablet" i don't think it works as you are not watching movies IN your tablet - technically the movie may be "inside" the computer, but you are not WATCHING it inside.

This raises a further question regarding whether you want to emphasise the watching or the receiving.  What you are actually talking about is the fact that you RECEIVE the movie directly (with no need to leave the house, as per your original indium), with the "watching" part being irrelevant.

For this reason, i would use "receive movies directly to your tablet" but I assume your intent is to be catchy and aim for marketing as well, so this may need to be reworked, but for the purposes of correct usage of words i believe this phrasing is more accurate.

Also, @ScotM 
Good response.  Tablets can be both a device to receive as well as to view, so a movie could be "delivered to" or "viewed on" the tablet, depending in whether the emphasis is on the watching or the receiving.

Comment: u r the one who gave me a close enough answer...maybe my next question should be 'catchy words for marketing.. emphasizing convenience'